# Erro: cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Na linha 14 está dando o erros "teclado cannot be resolved", vendo o print alguem sabe me dizer o pq ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, Diego!
Na proxima print tenta mostrar a caixa de dialog do erro, ela fica ali no cando esquerdo bem no inicio da linha.

Contudo, tenta importar o a classe **Scanner**, colocando este trecho de codigo no inicio da classe:

**import java.util.Scanner;**

public class Programa07part12 {